# How to get parameter hints/completion in Atom?

Tags: javascript, php, ide, atom-editor

I work a lot with web development with javascript, php and html.
Is it possible to get hints for functions and methods parameters?

writing array_column() would hit at the arguments the function takes and preferrably also show the return type (Array, String, Int etc). For example:

```
array_column ( array $array , int|string|null $column_key , int|string|null $index_key = null ) : array
```

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php

If it's not possible in Atom, i'd be happy to get recommendations on another IDE.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know a way of doing that directly in atom default,but you can download the TabNine extension which does a great job for function and parameter hints in all languages that it supports including PHP.
Another alternative would be to use PHPStorm which also has a good parameter hint systems.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).